# Android NIO - java.io.IOException: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: android, types, nio

I'm trying to write a very large file to another very large file. I'm receiving this error on the filechannel writing line and I'm unsure why. I thought it was because I was going out of the limits of the data type long but long can go up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and I'm only going up to 5,372,896,745 at the most. Any ideas why this is occurring? Is there some limit that MappedByteBuffer has? This doesn't occur for smaller files and I haven't run into any issues using the same code in a java desktop application. (Only happens on Android)

```
File f1 = new File(filename1); 

FileChannel fic, foc;
long fsize;
MappedByteBuffer mBUf;

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f1,true); 
foc = out.getChannel();

File f2 = new File(filename2);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f2); 

fic = in.getChannel();
fsize = fic.size();

for (long b = 0; b < fsize; b += 65536)
{
    if (fsize - b < Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE)
        mBUf = fic.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, b, fsize - b);
    else
        mBUf = fic.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, b, Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE);
    foc.write(mBUf); //ERROR HERE!
}               

fic.close();
in.close();
foc.close();
out.close();
```

Any ideas/feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some limit that MappedByteBuffer has?

Of course there is. It is limited by the available virtual memory for a start, and after that by the virtual address space.

You should be using `transferTo()` for this task rather than `MappedByteBuffers,`, as there is no agreed means of disposing of the virtual address space occupied by the latter.

Comment: I tried going the transferTo route instead but it was still throwing the same error.

Comment: @azdragon2 You will have to try a smaller transfer size. There is no advantage in specifying more than about a megabyte. By the structure of the `transferTo()` API you have to put it in a loop anyway, as it doesn't guarantee to transfer the amount requested. So do that and adjust the 'size' parameter to something sane.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately a Long does not go that high on a 32-bit system (which I believe Android is since it doesn't have over 4Gb of RAM).  Therefore the maximum length of an unsigned long on Android is 4,294,967,295 which means you are exceeding its limit.

Comment: I don't think it is the data type long in my for loop that's throwing the error, but you sent me on the right path. Apparently writing to a channel that is for a file of 2097215 KB or ~2.00006 GB is what is throwing this error. I was always under the impression that NIO it didn't load the entire file into memory? I'll have to search for alternative paths, thanks for the help!

Comment: @azdragon2 A `MappedByteBuffer` *maps* the entire file into memory. See the Javadoc. You don't want to do that!

Comment: A `Long` *definitely* goes that high on a 32-bit system. The size of `long` does *not* depend on the architecture. There may well be limitations in the NIO implementation, but that *doesn't* mean that the size of `long` itself is any different on Android.

Comment: This answer is just plain WRONG.