# VM won't let us allocate ... bytes

Tags: android, memory, file-transfer

So I am building an app which have a File Transfer application which allows you to transfer files from one folder inside the main folder to another. However, I am getting this error "VM won't let us allocate ... bytes".

Logcat Errors:

```
04-16 16:32:06.072: E/dalvikvm-heap(17644): 184440-byte external allocation too large for this process.
04-16 16:32:06.132: E/GraphicsJNI(17644): VM won't let us allocate 184440 bytes
```

Does anyone have a solution to overcome this? I saw several postings about images but not files.

Adding code: (As requested). Take note that this code is also copied elsewhere but there are a few modifications I made off my own.

```
private static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile)
            throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
            return;
    }
    if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
    }
    destFile = new File(destFile.toString().substring(0, destFile.toString().lastIndexOf('/')));
    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
            source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
```

As people have mentioned the memmory error is an image and yes thank you for finding my emberassing bug. I will rectify it soon after I finished this fileNotFoundException.

Sorry for long wait on the logcat to be updated forgot to add in a try and catch inside the copy file method which another method then catches another error from another method which displayed what was on top:

```
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/ActivityApp (Is a directory)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:66)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at tab.layout.FileFusionActivity.copyFile(FileFusionActivity.java:107)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at tab.layout.FileFusionActivity.onListItemClick(FileFusionActivity.java:78)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-16 18:19:41.322: W/System.err(4989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-16 18:19:41.332: W/System.err(4989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-16 18:19:41.332: W/System.err(4989):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: how are you copying those files? can you post the code?

Comment: The source code is added as requested.

Comment: That logcat from GraphicsJNI (which is the glue between Android Java code and the native Skia library) looks very much like a problem allocating bitmap data. Can you post the full logcat stack so that we can see which line in tour code is causing the issue?

Comment: Torid is correct the method I used didn't have a try and catch block which got another error from another catch block making it look like it was a memory culprit. Sorry everyone for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: i should have noticed it before but your log cat proves it. The error is in this line

```
destFile = new File(destFile.toString().substring(0, destFile.toString().lastIndexOf('/')));
```

change it to something like this

```
 destFile = new File(destFile.toString().substring(0, destFile.toString().lastIndexOf('/')),"hello.dat");
```

The error you are seeing might not be directly related to the copy process. Have you [profiled](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html#profiling) you app to check the memory usage?
Another thing you can try is to copy the file in chunks as outlined in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935214/android-nio-java-io-ioexception-value-too-large-for-defined-data-type)

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. I just added the logcat of the true error. Apparently I forgot to modify this method with a try and catch block so I was getting another exception elsewhere.

Comment: Yup you are right! I forgot the name. I kinda figured it out as well just right now was about to make an answer but didn't check till now.