# Value limits of primitive data types in android

Tags: java, android, long-integer

In my android application(Audio Processing) i use a long type variable to calculate the position where it is being paused, but the application gave me strange results for large audio files. After putting some effort i found out that the position calculation is going out of limits in android. Though a long type in java has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, i wondered why my calculation went out of limits.

After going through some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9935737/1219456) i found that android support limited value ranges unlike java. But my question is how i can perform this calculation in android? Is there any other android specific data types?

This is the calculation i perform in my app: 
position=((bufferSize*currentPosition)/duration);

Comment: The accepted answer in that post is simply wrong. Try it yourself - you'll find that you can definitely use a `long` up to the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in my comment, the post you're taking your information from is simply incorrect. `long` is always 64 bits. There may be some limitations in NIO, but that's a different matter.

However, your problem can easily be explained without any trickery. Here's your code again:

```
position = (bufferSize * currentPosition) / duration;
```

You haven't said what the types of `bufferSize` and `currentPosition` are, but I'll assume they're `long`. If you've got a very large buffer and a "late" `currentPosition` value, it's possible that the result of the multiplication will overflow into a negative number. When you divide that negative number by `duration`, you'll still get a negative (but smaller in magnitude) number.

If `bufferSize` and `currentPosition` are `int` variables instead of `long`, that overflow will occur much sooner. Indeed, if that's the case then you may well just be able to fix your problem just by forcing the arithmetic to be done in 64 bits:

```
position = ((long)bufferSize * currentPosition) / duration;
```

You should work out what range of `currentPosition` this would work up to, based on your buffer size - I'd expect it to be fine for any sensibly-sized file length and buffer size combination, to be honest.

If that doesn't help, please post more information - including the variable types and what values you're observing (for all variables, including the results).

Comment: bufferSize, currentPosition and duration are all int type.

Comment: as u said above, position = ((long)bufferSize * currentPosition) / duration,still it gives different value.

Comment: @user1219456: I assume you mean `int`? (There's no such type as `integer`.) If so, then that makes perfect sense - your multiplication is breaking the 2^31 barrier and overflowing.

Comment: @user1219456: "Different value"? It's hard to give you any help with such vague descriptions. Please post the values of all variables, and what you *expected* the result to be.

Comment: bufferize= 535680, current= 9527, duration= 33000 and position calculated is 24480. The expected value is 154649

Comment: @user1219456: 24498 is the value you get *without* changing the code... are you *certain* you've changed it correctly? I find it hard to believe that integer arithmetic is broken in Android, to be honest... I think it's much more likely to be a diagnostic failure. Can you edit your question with a short but complete snippet logging all the values, and then show the output?

Comment: @user1219456: "seems to be correct" isn't really enough when you're reporting something so surprising. As I say, please post a *complete* snippet demonstrating the problem, along with the log results. In nearly *every* case I've ever seen where something this surprising is reported, it turns out to be diagnostic error (e.g. reading the wrong variable in the debugger).

Comment: @user1219456: Okay, so that's *one* error with the reported results already. Is it too much to suggest that maybe you'd also made a mistake in terms of which code you were running? As I say, that's the result you would have got with the old code... *please* try again with the code involving the cast to `long`, and post a snippet including logging and the calculation, then the log output.

Comment: Okay, i have made the changes as pos=((long)(bufferSize*currentPosition)/duration); 
and now the values i got are bufferize= 508844, current= 8600, duration= 31000 and position calculated is 2615 which should be 141163

Comment: @user1219456: Right - thank you for posting the code. Now make it look like the code *I* posted, where the cast is *inside* the brackets, not outside. Currently you're casting *after* the overflow - you should be casting either `bufferSize` or `currentPosition`, to force the multiplication itself to be performed in `long` arithmetic. This is why it's *so* important to actually provide the code you're using - we could have solved this over half an hour ago if you'd just posted the code before.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jon Skeet, I guess a long is enough. But in the case a long is not large enough, you could consider divding your bufferSize by a thousand or by a million. You would loose some precision but the result would still be close to what your are looking for : you would approximate your buffer "fullness" in kilobytes or in megabytes instead of its value in bytes.